# Need RegEx to remove dots from a string only if there are more than one

Tags: regex, replace, preg-replace, keyword

Hello I have strings like

```
tda2030 100.200.300 circuit
```

I want to check if this string contains any keyword (separated by whitespace but can be on start or end) that contain more than 1 dot and then remove the dots.

The result should be

```
tda2030 100200300 circuit
```

in the example.
I tried a lot but I think I need a regex-pert :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a keyword?  Show more examples of what might pass and what might fail to require dot(s) to be removed. Show a regex you have tried.

Comment: what do you want ? its very unclear

Comment: Like when you use Google.. you put spaces between your keywords.

Why shall I post my wrong tries? I had something with [a-za-Z0-9]\.{2,} what is wrong..

Comment: @user3636110 By "what might fail to require ..." I mean some example of a string that you would NOT want to process.  So far as the rest, since this is not a code-writing service, it can be helpful to see where things went wrong, in both understanding your requirements, and also helping you to avoid similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting question because of your requirement to have multiple dots and the fact that PCRE does not allow infinite-width lookbehinds to see if we might have a dot behind us. We'll get over that limitation by using `\K` and `\G`.

Here is a regex that will find the right dots (see online [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qG4gI6))

```
(?<=\w)\.(?=\w+\.)|\G\w+\K\.
```

Use preg_replace to replace with an empty string:

```
$replaced = preg_replace("~(?<=\w)\.(?=\w+\.)|\G\w+\K\.~","",$string);
```

**How does it work?**

We have two cases separated by an `|` (OR)

1. Match a dot that is preceded by at least one word character and followed by some word characters and a dot
2. Match a dot that follows the previous match (which *had to* be a dot) and some word characters

Comment: @user3636110 You are welcome. Hey, I notice that you haven't yet voted on StackOverflow. If this answer or other answers solve your problems, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark on the left, as this is how the reputation system works (accepting an anwer gives reputation to both the answerer and to you). Of course there is no obligation to do so. Later when you have more reputation you can also upvote questions. Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO rep tutorial. :)